# Header propagation with quarkus amazon-lambda-rest not working

Tags: java, aws-lambda, http-headers, quarkus, resteasy

I am facing an issue while deploying the quarkus java code as native build. I am using java 17 with quarkus bom version of 3.5.1. The header propagation is working when I try from my local environment, but when I try to deploy as a native build to lambda its not working. Am I missing something here.

The following are the pom dependencies

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The following is the controller code

```
@Path(“/path")
@RegisterForReflection(serialization = true)
@Slf4j
public class Controller {

@Inject
Service service;

@POST
@Path(“/getHeader”)
public String getHeader(@HeaderParam(“firstHeader”) String headerField, RequestObject request) {
log.info("firstHeader: {}", headerField); // headerField is null
log.info("request name: {}", request.getName()); // this is working
return firstHeader;
}
```

I have tried the following approaches.

1. Tried to use interceptor to see if header was getting propagated. I am only able to see 2 header fields. Header fields that are visible are localhost and transfer-encoding.

2. Tried to implement a custom container Filter class to see if header is getting propagated. (ContainerRequestFilter)

Comment: Do you have anything infront of the Lambda? Like API Gateway for example?

Comment: I have an ALB, through which the path is routed to lambda service. There are no additional filters configured on the ALB. If I try using lambda function handler, its able to identify the headers @JCompetence

Comment: Found the root cause, I missed to enable multivalue headers in the target group for the ec2 instance. Thanks